# nginx not serving statick files django 4.1

Tags: python, django, nginx, deployment, gunicorn

I am new in deploy projects my static files not serving with nginx.

thats look my site-available/myprject file

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    
    location /static/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias /home/user/project/static;
    }
    
    location /media/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias /home/user/project/media;
    }

    location / {
     proxy_pass myIp:myPort;

    }
}
```

My static files and media have this path:

```
/home/user/project/staict files and media files
```

that's how it looks my settings.py configurations

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT =os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
```

my debug variable is false

I run collectstatic.

Comment: same problem here, waiting for someone to answer but just of curiosity are you deploying on aws lightsails ?

Comment: i deploying aws and but I think it should work the same. you tried change youre static_root? i tried everthing and not working

Comment: hm, i see. i am doing pretty much the same, also  django + ngixn + gunicorn on aws (lightsails) instance and my static files (javascript/react) were not served by the instance even though i provided the path to my frontend build path and provided STATIC variable in django's settings.py. followed 2 tutorials: [official](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=maEvGfJKWdU) and [unofficial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnrgBeIRtvo&list=LL&index=4).did not help.

Comment: It would help if you added your settings.py to your question.  Did you run `python manage.py collectstatic`?  You need to in production.  This will collect all static files and put them in a folder called `staticfiles`, in which case your nginx should have `location /staticfiles/`.

Comment: yes i run collectstatic with this STATIC_ROOT =os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'). i change the location /static/ to location /staticfiles in my available/project file annd not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I see that this different from my working Django site:

````
    server_name mydomain;```
should be->

```listen 80;
    server_name myIP;```

```alias /home/user/project/static;``` 
should be ->

```alias /home/user/project/static/;```

```location / {
     proxy_pass myIp:myPort;``` 
should be ->

```locatinon /{ 
      include        proxy_params;
      proxy_pass     http://myIp:myPort; ```

then

```STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT =os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')```
should be ->

```STATIC_URL = '/static/'
   STATIC_ROOT = /home/user/project/static;
   STATICFIES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
   ]```


This is the way my website is setup and it is working totally fine. However. if you change your static files, you will need to rerun "collecstatic."
````

Comment: i tried and when i run collectstatic i have this error
(staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.

and this too

(staticfiles.W004) The directory '/home/user/proejct/static/' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.

Comment: Is it /usr/project/static/ or /usr/proejct/static/?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem this way:

First you have to add in youre urlpatterns in urls.py

```
static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

2. create dir in /var/www/html/static
3. sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/static
4. Run collectstatic
5. set your location in sites-available/project (you nginx config)

Comment: This is for development where you set `DEBUG = True`, not for production.  Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development).